# SQLITE tables not operating concurrently

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am at a fix.. Please help me out.. I am new to IOS development and am developing a Shopping Cart Application in IOS.. My application consists some features like- Displays list of products, user can add some, edit their Quantities in detailViewController which will be updated in the db and can even delete them and at the end it gives the overall summary of the products bought, cost etc..

Each user has a login, it will validate the user name, password and allows the users etc..

Till to date everything was fine.. The database transactions are done using SQLITE.. But when I am trying to manipulate both the user and the products mdule together, the database manipulation of only one module works. ie, either the user login or the products manipulations works.. But not both.. Individually they are working fine...

But if i try to login by manipulating the db entries, add the products and try to edit them only either the user login manipulation in the db will work or the product manipulations.. Am at a fix..

Please tell me that Why am i encountering this problem and how can i debug it?? Thanks a million in advance.. Please help me out... Thanks